# The Ntext And Image Data Types Cannot Be Used In WHERE, HAVING, GROUP BY, ON, Or IN Clauses

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am getting an error:

> The ntext and image data types cannot
>   be used in WHERE, HAVING, GROUP BY,
>   ON, or IN clauses, except when these
>   data types are used with the LIKE or
>   IS NULL predicates while trying to
>   save the changes to SQLCE tables.

Please note this is an update operation.

I have version 3.5.1.0 of SQLCE installed.

Below is the error message and stack trace with the code:

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException
>   was unhandled   Message=The ntext and
>   image data types cannot be used in
>   WHERE, HAVING, GROUP BY, ON, or IN
>   clauses, except when these data types
>   are used with the LIKE or IS NULL
>   predicates.   Source=SQL Server
>   Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
>   HResult=-2147217900
>   NativeError=25923
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method,
>   ResultSetOptions options)
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query, QueryInfo queryInfo,
>   IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   parentArgs, Object[] userArgs,
>   ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object
>   lastResult)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression
>   query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos,
>   IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[]
>   subQueries)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query)
>   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicUpdate(TrackedObject
>   item)
>   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Update(TrackedObject
>   item)
>   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode
>   failureMode)
>   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode
>   failureMode)

Code causing the error:

```
var storedBug = DataContext.Bug_Tables.Where(b => b.Id.Equals(bugToSave.Id)).FirstOrDefaul(); 

storedBug.Name = bugToSave.Name;
storedBug.DeveloperId = bugToSave.Developer == null ? null : bugToSave.Developer.Id; 
storedBug.TesterId = bugToSave.Tester == null ? null : bugToSave.Tester.Id; 
storedBug.AssignedPersonId = bugToSave.AssignedPerson == null ? null : bugToSave.AssignedPerson.Id; 
storedBug.BugAreaId = bugToSave.BugArea.Id;
storedBug.BugStatusId = bugToSave.Status.Id;
storedBug.PriorityId = bugToSave.Priority == null ? null : bugToSave.Priority.Id; 
storedBug.Description = bugToSave.Description;
storedBug.Notes = bugToSave.Notes;
storedBug.Replication = bugToSave.Replication;
storedBug.FixedInBuild = bugToSave.FixInBuild;

DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Comment: I had forgotton to mention that the Description and note fields store RTF strings. And also I am able to insert data fine but its only the updates that fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/eca752c8-f921-44cf-a35b-5ecb14cc3134 which has all the answers

Comment: Summation of the link: `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is not supported by SQL CE. I changed my code to use `NVARCHAR(4000)` instead.

Comment: I've already came to SO to get the answer and yet you redirect me to another website. Seriously.